# exim4 authentication with external smtp server for smarthost

Tags: exim, smarthost

**/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf**

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost' # was local
dc_other_hostnames='' # was mini31
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost='mini31'
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='send.one.com:465' # Yes, two colons.
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

**/etc/exim/passwd.client**

```
target:send.one.com:my-real-address@something.com:MyTopSecretPassword
```

**/etc/email-addresses**

```
localusername:my-real-address@something.com
```

**/var/log/exim4/mainlog**

```
2022-07-10 23:03:49 1oAf1p-0004w0-GD <= my-real-address@something.com U=rwb P=local S=355
2022-07-10 23:03:49 1oAf1p-0004w0-GD H=send.one.com [2a02:2350:5:20e::2] Network is unreachable
2022-07-10 23:03:49 1oAf1p-0004w0-GD H=send.one.com [2a02:2350:5:20e::1] Network is unreachable
```

or sometimes

```
mini31 # tail /var/log/exim4/mainlog
2022-07-10 23:05:28 1oAf1p-0004w0-GD Spool file is locked (another process is handling this message)
2022-07-10 23:05:28 End queue run: pid=19276
2022-07-10 23:08:49 1oAf1p-0004w0-GD H=send.one.com [46.30.211.141]: SMTP timeout after initial connection: Connection timed out
2022-07-10 23:08:49 1oAf1p-0004w0-GD == my-real-address@something.com R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost defer (110): Connection timed out H=send.one.com [46.30.211.141]: SMTP timeout after initial connection
2022-07-10 23:10:58 exim 4.92 daemon started: pid=19694, -q30m, listening for SMTP on [127.0.0.1]:25 [::1]:25
2022-07-10 23:10:58 Start queue run: pid=19695
2022-07-10 23:10:58 1oAf1p-0004w0-GD == my-real-address@something.com R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host for 'rwb.me.uk'
2022-07-10 23:10:58 End queue run: pid=19695
2022-07-10 23:11:26 1oAf9C-00057u-P5 <= root@mini31 U=root P=local S=330
2022-07-10 23:11:26 1oAf9C-00057u-P5 == my-real-address@something.com R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host for 'rwb.me.uk'
```

** Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender**

```
...
  my-real-address@something.com
    host send.one.com [46.30.211.141]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data:
    530 5.7.0 Authentication required
...
```

```
mini31 # mailq
12m   355 1oAf1p-0004w0-GD <my-real-address@something.com> (rwb)
          my-real-address@something.com

 4m   330 1oAf9C-00057u-P5 <root@mini31>
          my-real-address@something.com
```

**Question**

WTF is going on and why isn't it working?

One.com seem to say port 465 and SSL/TLS. Do I need to enter *SSL/TLS* into `exim4` somehow?
I'm pretty sure they need the from address to be my-real-address@something.com -- do I need to set that somehwere?

Do I need to remove junk from `mail1q`?

Answer (score 0):

Not `target:` in `passwd.client`.

Use `satellite` instead of `smarthost` because no local mail is required -- everything should go to the real address.

Changed `dc_other_hostnames` back to `mini31` and `dc_readhost` to `omething.com`. Don't know why; it's unclear what these do.